# Selecionar um valor numérico de um menu suspenso usando Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dropdown, automatização, dropdownlist

Estou usando Python + Selenium para selecionar opções dentro de menus suspensos usando Select de acordo com valor da célula de uma planilha de Excel.
Com valores de texto consigo normalmente, porém, com valores numéricos não está funcionando.

Já tentei utilizando tanto:

```
drop.select_by_visible_text(dia_nascimento)
```

Quanto:

```
drop.select_by_value(dia_nascimento)
```

Mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Segue parte do código:

```
# Percorre a tabela e armazena as variáveis de acordo com os valores das células 
for i, nome in enumerate(tabela["Nome(s)"]):
    dia_nascimento = tabela.loc[i, "Dia de nasc"]
    pais_nasc = tabela.loc[i, "País de nascimento"]

    # A seleção do país funciona normalmente.
    x = navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'formularioComenzarRegistracion:cbNacionalidad')
    drop = Select(x)
    drop.select_by_visible_text(pais_nasc)
    
    # A seleção do dia de nascimento não funciona
    x = navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'formularioComenzarRegistracion:diaNacimiento')
    drop = Select(x)
    drop.select_by_value(dia_nascimento)
```

Segue o link do site em questão:

https://www.comunidadcoto.com.ar/comunidad/acceso.jsf

Para acessar a tela onde está o tal menu suspenso com itens numéricos que não estou conseguindo selecionar, é preciso clicar em "REGISTRATE", selecionar "CI" e digitar "87654123" no campo do número do documento, e ai sim avançar para a tela onde está o menu que está tirando meu sono.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver transformando o valor em string e em seguida arredondando o valor usando round, já que os itens do menu do site eram números inteiros, e o pandas estava reconhecendo os valores de Excel com uma casa decima depois da vírgula (do ponto na verdade). Ou seja, "1997" para o pandas era "1997.0", o que causava incompatibilidade com o valor do menu do site, já que lá está "1997".

Bastou alterar para:

```
drop.select_by_visible_text(str(round(dia_nascimento)))
```